# How can I make VScode's type suggestions more readable?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Currently VScode shows type hints on very, very wide lines:
[image]

It's hard for me to work out what value I am setting or each of the long list of parameters. Instead of:

```
getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection: Connection, payer: Signer, mint: PublicKey, owner: PublicKey, allowOwnerOffCurve?: boolean, commitment?: Commitment, confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions, programId?: PublicKey, associatedTokenProgramId?: PublicKey): Promise<...>
```

It would nicer to have something like:

```
getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection: Connection, 
  payer: Signer, 
  mint: PublicKey, 
  owner: PublicKey, 
  allowOwnerOffCurve?: boolean, 
  commitment?: Commitment, 
  confirmOptions?: ConfirmOptions, 
  programId?: PublicKey, 
  associatedTokenProgramId?: PublicKey
):  Promise<...>
```

**How can I make VScode's type suggestions more readable?** I'm hoping for something I can tweak in IntelliSense settings etc.

Comment: But the details view shows the parameters and their docstrings in separate lines. What's wrong with that? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: not sure if "details view" is the official term for what I'm referring to. I'm just talking about the documentation section of the suggestions popup. "Retrieve the associated token account \[...\["

Comment: @user docstrings omit types, see the screenshot in the question. The question is about making the type suggestions more readable.